# How to break GCM that uses the same IV

Tags: gcm

I have an implementation that natively uses the same IV (12 bytes of `0`) for all encryption. The key is always a 32 byte SHA-512 hash. I know via this [post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/57645/is-using-the-same-iv-in-aes-similar-to-not-using-an-iv-in-the-first-place) that I can

1. deduce the bit-wise XOR of the two plaintexts.
2. deduce the internal authentication value, and thus modify the ciphertexts without being detected.

How can I achieve either of these?

Comment: What research have you done to answer these questions?  Can you quote a definition of AES-GCM in algebraic equations that you can manipulate?

Comment: Funny, I cannot find a post that explains point 2.; I'm sure I saw that one. 1. is of course easy, just perform a many-time-pad attack on the CTR mode that forms the ciphertext (minus  the authentication tag).

Comment: Actually, it should not be that hard. You know that $t \oplus t'$ XOR's the encryption of the first counter value from the equation, and then you've just GMAC *over known data* (the authenticaton data and ciphertext) with the only unknown being $H$, and no one way functions in there.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Try `joux' "forbidden attack"`.

Comment: This image on twitter already supplies the TL;DR :) https://twitter.com/tqbf/status/760910618228424704