# "hex" vs. "base64" encoding when enciphering

Tags: encryption, encoding, decryption

Examining different implementations of encryption / decryption  with cipher on Node.js, I paid attention that some implementations use `hex` encoding:

```
let encrypted = cipher.update(value, "utf8", "hex");
```

while other prefer `base64`:

```
let encrypted = cipher.update(value, "utf8", "base64");
```

**Questions:**

1. Does encoding choice play a significant role in encryption for a cipher?
2. From security point of view, can the wrong encoding choice affect the outcome?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99176/discussion-on-question-by-mike-b-hex-vs-base64-encoding-when-enciphering).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does encoding choice play a significant role in encryption for a cipher?

No.  Ciphers operate on bit strings.  It is far more important to focus on what kind of ‘cipher’ it is and what security goals it provides: you generally want an **authenticated cipher** like NaCl crypto_secretbox_xsalsa20poly1305 or AES-GCM, and you definitely don't want to reach for the letters A-E-S directly yourself.  Focus on [security contracts](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/57648).

> From security point of view, can the wrong encoding choice affect the outcome?

Not as far as the *cryptography* is concerned, but complicated encoding methods can pose security problems of their own:

- If you apply a base64 encoder/decoder to the *plaintext* rather than *ciphertext* you might leak information about the plaintext via timing side channels in a naive array lookup for hexadecimal digits.
- If you apply compression to the plaintext you might leak information about it via the length of the ciphertext as a side channel.
- If your encoding method is buggy like an ASN.1 parser your application might barf its memory contents out like a bleeding-heart OpenSSL.

Comment: Thanks for the addressing both of my questions. I'll check the subject of timing attack more deeply.